# Using JetCreator for an android app

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to use JetCreator to create sounds for my application and I can't figure out how the install it. As said in the JetCreator user's manual, I have installed Python (3.4) and wxPython. Unfortunately, I can't find any "jetCreator.py" file in the android sdk folder (the "jet" directory is not present in the "android-sdk/tools" folder).

Is JetCreator still available? Where can I find it? And where could I find an up-to-date user's manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...had the same problem, should be answeredhere too.

See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75498

Kind regards, helmut.

Comment: It might be more helpful if you could include the actual answer as to where the information is available for the OP, instead of just a link.